# How to add a string to a specific line in a file using sed?

Tags: sed

I have the following file test.txt

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
```

I want to add the string "1" next to it after a space next to the word node2 using sed so it looks like this.

```
node1
node2 1
node3
node4
```

I tried `sed  '/node2/a 1' test.txt` but it adds a new line. How do I just add a space followed by a 1.

Comment: `s/node2/node2 1/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is for adding new lines. Use `s` to modify the line in place.

```
sed '/node2/s/$/ 1/' test.txt
```

Comment: this is perfect, if you dont mind could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945793/using-sed-to-replace-a-character-in-a-specific-line-and-multiple-lines

Comment: You need to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. `awk` would be easier for that problem.